# how to setup cloudfront frontend and backend under same domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have the following infrastructure:

**FRONT-END**: built with React and pushed the codes to an aws s3 bucket then created a cloudfront distribution and Route53 hosted zone to connect the two. (this works fine and i can access the website on `http s://www.foo.com`)

Now my question is how do I connect the frontend above to the backend of a load balancer to the subdomain `api.foo.com`

(On the application side, on the local machine, i know how to do it, you just make the call to a backend endpoint `http://localhost:5000/...` as an example but my question is about `cloudfront`).

How do I configure it to achieve the above?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. So your load balancer does not work? What is the actual issue with `api.foo.com`?

Comment: @Marcin i want to understand how to connect a backend app built with a load balancer on aws to the front end cloudfront distribution created with the configuration mentioned above. when it is connected i want the http request from the front end to call the back end on the url `api.foo.com` (subdomain of `www.foo.com`)